# drupal 7 chain forms

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a form A and a form B.

I would like to make form A redirect the user to form B AND inform form B of the choices made in form A

**Form A's submit function (does not work):**

```
function recruitment_select_team_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
    // Forward to the next page.
    $items['yourmod/foo/%/delete'] = array(
    'title' => 'goto next page',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('recruitment_form', 1), // second argument is the paramter for the team_id (test value)
    //'access arguments' => array('delete foo rows'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}
```

**Form B's form:**

```
function recruitment_form()
{
    $team_id = 1;
    if(db_query('select count(*) from gm_team where id = :team_id',array(':team_id' => $team_id))->fetchfield() == 0)
    {
        die('Sorry but the team with team ID '.$team_id.' does not exist. If you feel this is a mistake please contact us.');
    }
    $team_terms = db_query('select terms from gm_team where id = :team_id',array(':team_id' => $team_id))->fetchfield();
    $team_requirements = db_query('select recruit_requirements from gm_team where id = :team_id',array(':team_id' => $team_id))->fetchfield();  

......
}
```

Comment: You can use 1) Db to store the data to that both the forms can access it. 2) As  for a redirect you can do that with jquery

Comment: [This](http://growingventuresolutions.com/blog/drupal-7-multistep-forms-using-variable-functions) might help you

Comment: hakanito's link is the proper way to handle this, unless you really have a good reason not to make it a multiform.

Comment: Indeed hakanito's link is a great solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hanito's link to multiform example in the comments to your question would be my first recommendation... however if you really need form B to be a separate form or that's beyond your control, you could probably just store the form values of form A in a session var, and then set the $form['redirect'] value to the path of form b.

example.

```
function recruitment_select_team_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
    // Forward to the next page.
    $items['yourmod/foo/%/delete'] = array(
    'title' => 'goto next page',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('recruitment_form', 1), // second argument is the paramter for the team_id (test value)
    //'access arguments' => array('delete foo rows'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    $_SESSION['form_a_values'] = $form_state['values'];
    $form['redirect'] = 'path/to/form/B';
}
```